# Adding button to UICollectionView cells

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview, uibutton, swift4, uicollectionviewcell

How to add a button to each horizontal collection view cell and link it to an action programmatically in swift 4

Answer (score 0):

**Do like this Connect Button** `IBAction` **in you CollectionViewCell Class.**

```
class PhotosCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

   @IBAction func DeleteTapped(_ sender: Any) {

       if let OnDeleteTapped = self.OnDeleteTapped {
            OnDeleteTapped(self)
       }
   }

   var OnDeleteTapped : ((PhotosCollectionViewCell) -> Void)? = nil   
}
```

**Use this in CollectionView Delegate method.**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotosCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotosCollectionViewCell

    cell.OnDeleteTapped = { cell in
          // Do Anything Here is Your Action Event
    }

    return cell
}
```